# Correct way to set expl3 sequences in the aux file

Tags: expl3, auxiliary-files, l3seq

Consider the following example, in which it (globally) adds an element `TEST` to the sequence `\g__mymodule_test_seq` in the `.aux` file. Then if it is asked to show the sequence content immediately in the aux file, the result is correct (this is the commented code). However, if later asked to show in the document, it shows that the sequence is empty. Why would this happen, considering that the `\seq_gput_right:Nn` is indeed the global version? What is the correct way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g__mymodule_test_seq

\iow_now:cx { @auxout }
  {
    \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOn
    ^^J
    \token_to_str:N \seq_gput_right:Nn \token_to_str:N \g__mymodule_test_seq {TEST}
    ^^J
    \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOff
  }


%% This shows empty
\seq_show:N \g__mymodule_test_seq

%% This shows "TEST"
% \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
%   {
%     \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOn
%     ^^J
%     \token_to_str:N \seq_show:N \token_to_str:N \g__mymodule_test_seq
%     ^^J
%     \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOff
%   }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

The content of the `.aux` file is:

```
\relax 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_gput_right:Nn\g__mymodule_test_seq{TEST}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Comment: I don't think that it is good idea to write lots of \ExplSyntaxON/Off to the aux. Write a command `\jin@gput@seq` and push `\jin@gput@seq{TEST}` to the aux.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for this advice. In my package I am doing this, it's just in this MWE I would like to keep things simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The allocation of the variable should be done in the preamble, before the `.aux` file is read in.
2. At the first run, you get empty, because the `.aux` file is empty.
3. At the next run, you get

   ```
   The sequence \g__mymodule_test_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
   >  {TEST}.
   ```

Full code, where `\seq_show:N` can be before or after the `\iow_now:ce` instruction (nowadays preferred to `\iow_now:cx`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g__mymodule_test_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_now:ce { @auxout }
  {
    \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOn
    ^^J
    \token_to_str:N \seq_gput_right:Nn \token_to_str:N \g__mymodule_test_seq {TEST}
    ^^J
    \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOff
  }

\seq_show:N \g__mymodule_test_seq

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, with your given code, I am still getting `The sequence \g__mymodule_test_seq is empty`, no matter how many times I compile.

Comment: @Jinwen I get exactly what I described. So you're doing something else you're not telling. By the way, if you use `\iow_now:cn` you can dispense with `\token_to_str:N`.

Comment: Oh, I understand. It seems to be my editor, whenever I am using `\seq_show:N`, it interprets the result as a compilation failure, so the next time it shall delete the temporary files, as a result, the aux file content is lost in the process.

Comment: Please allow me to ask a follow-up question. I was being told that with TeX Live 2023 on overleaf, `\iow_now:ce` would lead to "Undefined control sequence" error. Thus would it be possible to use `\iow_now:cx` in this case? I was a bit concerned about this since `\iow_now:cx` does not seem to have appeared in `interface3.pdf`.

Comment: @Jinwen It's not in `interface3.pdf` because that document only lists the current release. But the older commands are still there, in order to ensure back compatibility. On the other hand, `\iow_now:ce` runs on an updated TL 2023.

Comment: Yes, since I am using TL 2024, I didn't notice that this would lead to potential issue. For back compatibility, is it possible to somehow tell the compiler to switch to the `cx` version if the `ce` version is not available?

Comment: @Jinwen You can alwasy do `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_now:Nn { ce }` and it will work in several previous releases, starting from 2018.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! :-)