# TeX capacity exceeded due to misuse of \l_tmpa_clist

Tags: errors, compilation-error, debugging, multifootnote

I am trying to improve my package `multifootnote`, hoping that it could correctly place the footnote text on the corresponding pages when the footnote marks are distributed over several pages. For this, I am trying to write the page number, footnote mark and text information to the aux file, and read them back via the main commands.

However, the current testing version would show the following error on the second run (which seems to suggest that there is something wrong with the information being read back from the aux file):

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
\l_tmpa_clist ->\ref *{\l_tmpa_clist
```

After some debugging, the issue seems to be with the `\__multifootnote_print_footnotetext:nn` (see the code below), in the sense that if I comment the corresponding part the code would run without issue (though without the most important feature of this package). This is a command for actually printing the `\footnotetext`. However, I didn't modify this part of code, it is directly copied from the old version, the only change is that I decided to make the code a separate macro this time.

At first I thought that it is due to that `\g__multifootnote_mark_internal_per_page_seq` is empty, which is the sequence of footnote markers and texts to be printed, this leads me to ask [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/713686/194994). However, from its answer, it seems that the problem is not actually here.

Is there any suggestion on what I could look for next? Currently I have no clue why this error would occur, and since printing the footnote text is the key of this modification, without being able to print the result I don't even know how to guess where is going wrong.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multifootnote,hyperref}
\begin{document}

% First approach
Lorem ipsum\footnotenumber[fn1] dolor\footnotenumber[fn2] sit amet\footnotenumber[fn3], \clearpage
consectetur\footnotenumber[fn4] adipiscing elit\footnotenumber[fn5].
\multifootnote[fn1,fn2,fn5]{This is a footnote for demonstration.}
\multifootnote[fn1,fn3,fn4]{This is another footnote for demonstration.}

\end{document}
```

Here is the testing version of `multifootnote.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2022-06-01]
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {multifootnote}
  {2024/03/20*} {}
  {Multiple numbers for the same footnote}

\msg_new:nnn { multifootnote }
  { non-compatible-package }
  { "multifootnote" ~ is ~ not ~ compatible ~ with ~ the ~ package ~ "#1". }

\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument/before } { multifootnote }
  {
    \@ifpackageloaded { footnotebackref }
      {
        \msg_warning:nnn { multifootnote } { non-compatible-package } { footnotebackref }
      } {}
  }

\dim_new:N \l_multifootnote_space_after_comma_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l_multifootnote_space_after_comma_dim { 0.2ex }

\bool_new:N  \l__multifootnote_left_indent_bool
\bool_set_false:N  \l__multifootnote_left_indent_bool
\dim_new:N \l__multifootnote_left_indent_dim

\keys_define:nn { multifootnote }
  {
    , left-align    .bool_set:N = \l__multifootnote_left_align_bool
    , left-align    .initial:n  = { false }
    , left~align    .bool_set:N = \l__multifootnote_left_align_bool
    , left align    .bool_set:N = \l__multifootnote_left_align_bool
    , left-indent   .code:n     = {
                                    \bool_set_true:N \l__multifootnote_left_indent_bool
                                    \dim_set:Nn \l__multifootnote_left_indent_dim { #1 }
                                  }
    , left-indent   .default:n  = { 1.5em }
    , left~indent   .code:n     = {
                                    \bool_set_true:N \l__multifootnote_left_indent_bool
                                    \dim_set:Nn \l__multifootnote_left_indent_dim { #1 }
                                  }
    , left~indent   .default:n  = { 1.5em }
    , left indent   .code:n     = {
                                    \bool_set_true:N \l__multifootnote_left_indent_bool
                                    \dim_set:Nn \l__multifootnote_left_indent_dim { #1 }
                                  }
    , left indent   .default:n  = { 1.5em }
    , unknown       .code:n     = {}
  }
\ProcessKeyOptions [ multifootnote ]

\cs_new_protected:Nn \multifootnote_make_footnote_left_align:n
  {
    \renewcommand { \@makefntext } [1]
      {
        \skip_horizontal:n { #1 }
        \tl_if_blank:eF { \text_expand:n { \@thefnmark } }
          {
            \@makefnmark
            \nobreakspace
          }
        ##1
      }
  }

\bool_if:NT \l__multifootnote_left_align_bool
  {
    \multifootnote_make_footnote_left_align:n { 0pt }
  }
\bool_if:NT \l__multifootnote_left_indent_bool
  {
    \multifootnote_make_footnote_left_align:n { \l__multifootnote_left_indent_dim }
  }

\tl_new:N \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl
\seq_new:N \l__multifootnote_tmp_seq

% First approach
\prop_new:N \g__multifootnote_mark_pagenumber_prop
\seq_new:N \g__multifootnote_mark_internal_seq
\seq_new:N \g__multifootnote_mark_internal_per_page_seq
\cs_new:Nn \__multifootnote_process_per_page_mark:nnN
  {
    \tl_clear:N #3
    \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      {
        \prop_get:NnN \g__multifootnote_mark_pagenumber_prop { ##1 } \l_tmpa_tl
        % only keep those labels that appear on the current page
        \str_if_eq:eeT { \thepage } { \l_tmpa_tl }
          {
            \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { ##1 }
          }
      }
    \tl_put_right:No #3 { { \l_tmpa_clist } }
    \tl_put_right:Nn #3 { { #2 } }
  }
\hook_gput_code:nnn { shipout } { multifootnote }
  {
    % reinitialize the per page footnotetext list
    \seq_gset_eq:NN \g__multifootnote_mark_internal_per_page_seq \g__multifootnote_mark_internal_seq
    % leave only those labels appeared on the current page
    \seq_clear:N \l__multifootnote_tmp_seq
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g__multifootnote_mark_internal_per_page_seq
      {
        \__multifootnote_process_per_page_mark:nnN #1 \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl
        \seq_put_right:No \l__multifootnote_tmp_seq { \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl }
      }
    \seq_gset_eq:NN \g__multifootnote_mark_internal_per_page_seq \l__multifootnote_tmp_seq
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \@multifootnote@add@to@mark@pagenumber@list { m m }
  {
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g__multifootnote_mark_pagenumber_prop { #1 } { #2 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotemark { O{} }
  {
    % print the footnote mark
    \footnotemark
    \group_begin:
      \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
        {
          \addtocounter { footnote } { -1 }
          \refstepcounter { footnote }
          \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
            {
              \cs_gset_eq:NN \@currentHref \Hy@footnote@currentHref
            } {}
          \label { #1 }
        }
    \group_end:
    % write the corresponding pagenumber to aux file
    \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
      {
        \@multifootnote@add@to@mark@pagenumber@list { #1 } { \thepage }
      }
    % print the corresponding footnote text
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g__multifootnote_mark_internal_per_page_seq
      {
        \__multifootnote_print_footnotetext:nn ##1
      }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \__multifootnote_print_footnotetext:nn
  {
    \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
    \clist_clear:N \l_tmpb_clist
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
      {
        \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
          {
            \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
              {
                \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
                  { \ref*{ ##1 } }
                \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_clist
                  { \Hy@raisedlink { \hypertarget { \getrefbykeydefault{##1}{anchor}{Doc-Start} } {} } }
              }
              {
                \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
                  { \ref { ##1 } }
              }
          }
        \def \thefootnote { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { , \skip_horizontal:n { \l_multifootnote_space_after_comma_dim } } }
        \@ifpackageloaded { hyperref }
          {
            \xdef \Hy@footnote@currentHref { x\Hy@footnote@currentHref }
          } {}
        \footnotetext { \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpb_clist {} \ignorespaces #2 }
      }
  }
\NewCommandCopy \footnotenumber \multifootnotemark

\NewDocumentCommand \@multifootnote@add@to@mark@text@list { m m }
  {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g__multifootnote_mark_internal_seq { { #1 } { #2 } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotetext { O{} m }
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 }
      {
        \footnotetext { #2 }
      }
      {
        \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
          {
            \@multifootnote@add@to@mark@text@list { #1 } { #2 }
          }
      }
  }

% Second approach
% \seq_new:N \g__multifootnote_tag_internal_seq
% \seq_new:N \g__multifootnote_tag_internal_per_page_seq
% \hook_gput_code:nnn { shipout } { multifootnote }
%   {
%     \seq_gset_eq:NN \g__multifootnote_tag_internal_per_page_seq \g__multifootnote_tag_internal_seq
%   }

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotetag { m }
  {
    \footnotemark
    \group_begin:
      \def \thefootnote {}
      \footnotetext { \vspace { -\baselineskip } }
    \group_end:
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      {
        \cs_if_exist:cTF { multifootnote-tag- ##1 }
          {
            \tl_gput_right:cx { multifootnote-tag- ##1 } { , \skip_horizontal:n { \l_multifootnote_space_after_comma_dim } \thefootnote }
          }
          {
            \cs_gset:cpx { multifootnote-tag- ##1 } { \thefootnote }
          }
      }
  }
\NewCommandCopy \footnotetag \multifootnotetag

\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnotetagtext { O{} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 }
        {
          \def \thefootnote { }
        }
        {
          \def \thefootnote { \use:c { multifootnote-tag- #1 } }
        }
      \footnotetext { #2 }
    \group_end:
  }

% The combined interface for producing footnote text
\NewDocumentCommand \multifootnote { O{} m }
  {
    \str_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { , }
      {
        \multifootnotetext [ #1 ] { #2 }
      }
      {
        \multifootnotetagtext [ #1 ] { #2 }
      }
  }

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `multifootnote.sty'.
```

The expected output of the MWE should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the contents of the aux file after the first run?

Comment: I don't know the package, but `\l_tmpa_clist ->\ref *{\l_tmpa_clist` looks like a circular definition. Besides `\ref *{\l_tmpa_clist` looks wrong by itself.

Comment: `\__multifootnote_process_per_page_mark:nnN #1 \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl` doesn't look right. You have an argument spec of `nnN` but are passing `#1` for `nn`. Also `\tl_put_right:No <variable> { {\l_tmpa_clist} }` adds the variable and not its value, which is probably not what you want. You're basically saying `\tl_put_right:Nn <variable> { \l_tmpa_clist }`.

Comment: However, I don't know your package and I'm not sure what the other argument is meant to be. I tried to figure out by comparison with the current version, but that doesn't produce the target output, so didn't prove especially enlightening. I also doubt you should `gset` a `\g_variable` to an `\l_variable`, but I'm not certain about this. You seem to be changing things between different types of data and it's not always clear why (e.g. tl to clist to ... etc.).

Comment: @cfr `\__multifootnote_process_per_page_mark:nnN #1 \l__multifootnote_tmp_tl` is alright, since each item in `\g__multifootnote_mark_internal_per_page_seq` is a two-group token list. For example `\multifootnote[fn1,fn2,fn5]{This is a footnote for demonstration.}` adds `{fn1,fn2,fn5}{This is a footnote for demonstration.}` to that global sequence.

Comment: The `shipout` hook seems too late. At that time, content of the page to shipout is all decided, hence there's no chance to insert footnote to that page.

Comment: It seems at odd with the transparency the argument specifier is supposed to give, but I'm guessing it is the `\tl_put_right...` which is causing the problem.

Comment: See `ltshipout-doc.pdf` for information about where things happen and where they can be adjusted. Otherwise, correcting the expansion problem just gets you the footnotes on the following page. (And the numbering is kaput.)

Comment: `\tl_put_right:No #3 { { \l_tmpa_clist } }`  is wrong. Through the additional brace group the o-expansion doesn't reach the `\l_tmpa_clist`, you need `\tl_put_right:No #3 { \exp_after:wN { \l_tmpa_clist } }`.  Apart from this: writing \thepage per `\iow_now` looks definitively wrong. Page numbers should be written at shipout.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for this! Regarding the `\thepage` in `\iow_now`, I was actually trying to record the page number for the location of each label. Do you have suggestion on the correct way to do this?

Comment: Use the standard \label command, or ltproperties or zref.  They all know how to record data at shipout.